# check to see if an observable collection is empty ! c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

want to check if there are ant Items in an observable collection named PlayerProfile

```
if ((App.ViewModel.PlayerProfile.Count != 0))
{
  // remove stored PlayerProfile
}
```

Anyideas ??

gettign a null error (even though there are

App.ViewModel.PlayerProfile is an oberservable collection containg players

i just want to check to see if its empty and if not delete or clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting a null error, there are three possibilities:

1. `App` is null (very unlikely)
2. `App.ViewModel` could be null.
3. The `PlayerProfile` property on `ViewModel` may be null.

I suggest making sure that `PlayerProfile` is being constructed in all constructors of your ViewModel, and that your ViewModel has been constructed at this point, as those are the most likely culprits.  Most likely, this routine is being called prior to your initialization methods, which is why these are unset at this point.

Comment: you've listed 3 possibilities :)

Comment: @Alan: Yeah, thanks - I figured App being null isn't real, so I left it off, but then I added it, since techncially, I believe you can force it to null ;)

Comment: I would feel really sad if he forced it to null.

Comment: i didn't force null -_- , but i did miss a line in app.viewmodel thanks reed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Count` property will return the number of elements in the collection.

However, if you're getting a null error, that means something is null.

Answer (score 0):

Either `App`, `ViewModel` or `PlayerProfile` is `null`.